# Simulate the 'new' operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I tried to simulate the 'new' operator in JavaScript in a code like this:

```
Function.method('new', function ( ) {
    var objPrototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
    var instance = this.apply(objPrototype, arguments);

    return instance;
});
```

However, in order to cover all the cases, the return statement should look like this:

```
return (typeof instance === 'object' && instance ) || objPrototype;
```

Now for the tests:

```
var SomeClass = function (param1, param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
};

var test1 = String.new('test1'); //in this case, the "instance" variable is an object
var test2 = SomeClass.new('test1', 'test2'); // in this case, the "instance" variable is undefined
```

Is this exactly what the 'new' operator does? Is there any case left to cover?

Comment: Umm... how about using the new operator? This seems somewhat like a reinvention of a rather old wheel.

Comment: Yep..but I still want to understand exactly what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: For educational purposes? Fair enough...

Comment: Just playing around with inheritance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1646698/1529630)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2):

> ### 11.2.2 The new Operator [#](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2) [Ⓣ](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2-toc) [Ⓡ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/new) [Ⓖ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#new)
>
> The production *NewExpression* : `new` *NewExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *NewExpression*.
> 2. Let *constructor* be [`GetValue`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1)(*ref*).
> 3. If [`Type`](http://es5.github.com/#Type)(*constructor*) is not Object, throw a [TypeError](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11.6.5) exception.
> 4. If *constructor* does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method, throw a [TypeError](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11.6.5) exception.
> 5. Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on *constructor*, providing no arguments (that is, an empty list of arguments).
>
> The production *MemberExpression* : `new` *MemberExpression Arguments*
>   is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let *ref* be the result of evaluating *MemberExpression*.
> 2. Let *constructor* be [`GetValue`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.7.1)(*ref*).
> 3. Let *argList* be the result of evaluating *Arguments*, producing an internal list of argument values ([11.2.4](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.4)).
> 4. If [`Type`](http://es5.github.com/#Type)(*constructor*) is not Object, throw a [TypeError](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11.6.5) exception.
> 5. If *constructor* does not implement the [[Construct]] internal method, throw a [TypeError](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11.6.5) exception.
> 6. Return the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method on *constructor*, providing the list *argList* as the argument values.

In either case, all steps are correctly followed:

```
var objPrototype = Object.create(this.prototype);    // 1-4 1-5
var instance = this.apply(objPrototype, arguments);  // 5   6
```

The point of interest is 2.
[The specification for `[[construct]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.2) states:

> When the [[Construct]] internal method for a Function object F is
>   called with a possibly empty list of arguments, the following steps
>   are taken:
>
> - Let obj be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
>     `. . .`
> - Let result be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of F, providing obj as the this value and providing the argument list
>     passed into [[Construct]] as args.
> - If [`Type`](http://es5.github.com/#Type)(*result*) is Object then return *result*.
> - Return *obj*.

`typeof obj` returns `"object"` for `null`, while `null` is not an object. However, since `null` is a falsy value, your code also works as intended:

```
return (typeof instance === 'object' && instance ) || objPrototype;
```

Comment: Hopefully JavaScript is compatible 100% with ECMASCript when it comes to the new operator. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: This answer forgets about the case when `this.prototype` is not a ES-Object. The value `null` will be accepted by `Object.create`, though it should use `Object.prototype` instead.

Comment: Actually the code is wrong when the constructor function returns a function object, for which `typeof` doesn't work well either. Better: `return (Object(instance) === instance) ? instance : objPrototype)`

Answer (score 8):

The `new` operator takes a function `F` and `arguments`: `new F(arguments...)`. It does three easy steps:

1. Create the instance of the class. It is an empty object with its
   `__proto__` property set to `F.prototype`. Initialize the instance.
2. The function F is called with the arguments passed and this set to
       be the instance.
3. Return the instance

Now that we understand what the new operator does, we can implement it in Javascript.

```
    function New (f) {
/*1*/  var n = { '__proto__': f.prototype };
       return function () {
/*2*/    f.apply(n, arguments);
/*3*/    return n;
       };
     }
```

And just a small test to see that it works.

```
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype = {
  print: function () { console.log(this.x, this.y); }
};

var p1 = new Point(10, 20);
p1.print(); // 10 20
console.log(p1 instanceof Point); // true

var p2 = New (Point)(10, 20);
p2.print(); // 10 20
console.log(p2 instanceof Point); // true
```

Comment: Closure to the rescue! Interesting approach.

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are all valid for standard ES5, which was all there when when they were written, but they are not general solutions that will work in all ES6 contexts, so I want to expand on them. The short answer is that the code from the question:

```
Function.method('new', function ( ) {
  var objPrototype = Object.create(this.prototype);
  var instance = this.apply(objPrototype, arguments);

  return instance;
});
```

would in a standard ES6 environment be better implemented as

```
Function.method('new', function ( ) {
  return Reflect.construct(this, arguments);
});
```

which definitely simplifies things.

`Reflect.construct` was introduced in ES6 as part of the `Proxy` system, but it has general uses like this situation.

The reason this is the preferred method now is the simple reason that `.apply` doesn't work on every type of function anymore. [The previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10429227/785065) explains that `new` calls the internal language function `[[Construct]]` to initialize the argument. The approach using `.apply` essentially replaces the automatic object-creation and calling logic handled in `[[Construct]]` by instead manually creating the object and then calling the function, which uses it's `[[Call]]` internal method instead of `[[Construct]]`.

The call to the function is part of what changed in ES6. In ES5 pretty much the only thing you'll be constructing is a normal `function Foo(){}` value, so you can make assumptions about that. In ES6, `class Foo {}` syntax was introduced, and the constructor functions created by class syntax have more restrictions in place, so the assumptions made about ES5 do not apply. Most importantly, ES6 classes are explicitly disallowed from using `[[Call]]`. Doing the following will throw an exception:

```
class Foo {}
Foo();
```

This is the same issue as `.call` and `.apply`. They are not function-constructing functions, they are function-calling functions. So if you try to use them on an ES6 class, they will throw exceptions.

`Reflect.construct` avoids these issues by *actually* calling `[[Construct]]` and not `[[Call]]`, but exposing it via an API that can be used without `new`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to using the [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) approach. Its in line with how the OP initially started out...

```
function New(fn) {
    var newObj = Object.create(fn.prototype);
    return function() {
        fn.apply(newObj, arguments);
        return newObj;
    };
}
```

This is a much cleaner way of doing it, and it passes prototype chain tests too.

Comment: Is there a typo? two consecutive return statements?

Comment: regarding the above typo, I had to use in my own code but gave me error until I changed it to "return fn.apply(newObj, arguments);" (instead of  "return newObj;"). Are the two supposed to be the same?

Comment: @nino.porcino Most _constructors_ don't return anything...I mean that is how we write them...therefore the `return fn.apply(...)` with give you `undefined`...