# Result of a `new` call, when no constructor is present. ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

Looking through the [meteor TODOs app](https://github.com/meteor/todos/blob/e86b9fea3eb6e74a32b020d6b0d4de83e82a73af/imports/api/lists/lists.js) I noticed a particular class pattern.

```
class ListsCollection extends Mongo.Collection {
  //Other methods, no constructor
}
export const Lists = new ListsCollection('lists');
```

This code uses `new`, though there is no `ListsCollection` constructor. My interpretation, is that the constructor of `Mongo.Collection` is being called by prototype delegation.

Throughout the rest of my code, I am using `Kyle Simpson's OLOO Pattern` and i would like to use the same pattern here.

```
const ListsCollection = {
  init() {
    //Call the constructor of Mongo.Collection
    return this;
  },
  //Same methods
}
Object.setPrototypeOf(ListsCollection, Mongo.Collection);
export const Lists = Object.create(ListsCollection).init('lists');
```

I've started, however I am not sure how to call the constructor of the `Mongo.Collection` class. Any suggestions would be appreciated :D.

EDIT - following answers

I have replaced the comment in my second code snippet with `Mongo.Collection.call(this)`, which should have the desired effect. However, i get the error `Error: use "new" to construct a Mongo.Collection`. I'm not sure the best way to work around this.

EDIT 2 - following investigation

The offending line found in the Mongo.Collection constructor function, causing the error is:

```
if (! (self instanceof Mongo.Collection))
  throw new Error('use "new" to construct a Mongo.Collection');
```

since `instanceof` tests for existence of `Mongo.Collection.prototype` up the prototype chain, it is clearly not present.

This was solved by changing

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(ListsCollection, Mongo.Collection);
```

To

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(ListsCollection, Mongo.Collection.prototype);
```

Comment: Why not stick with classes?

Comment: I usually would, I'm simply taking this pattern to completion to see how i feel about it at the end of a project. The advantages are described here: [relevant YDKJS chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md)

Comment: Is there something wrong with your first example?  It looks better to me, if Mongo.Collection.call is not working for you.

Comment: Mentioned in the comment above. I should be able to do it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do:

```
Mongo.Collection.call(this);
```

at the place you have your comment.

Remember that a class in JavaScript, either older versions and new ES6 version, is a function representing its own constructor.

Comment: Of course, it seems so obvious now... I was thinking something similar, e.g. `(new Mongo.Collection).bind(this)` however I was aware you cannot combine `bind` and `new`. Thanks for the answer, ill try it out

Comment: Unfortunately, using `Mongo.Collection.call(this)` I get the error: `Error: use "new" to construct a Mongo.Collection`

Comment: Solution in question edits. Since my edit to this answer has been accepted, i am marking it as the answer.

Comment: Well, check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428603/simulate-the-new-operator-in-javascript , you could try to simulate `new` operator aswel.

Comment: Keep in mind that the error explicitly says `use "new" to construct`, which this isn't doing. It'd totally valid for them to introduce something that would break when used with `.call` in the future without a semver major version bump.